# can't start activity in android

Tags: android, performance

When button click I want go to another xml layout file.
So i wrote start new activity as following way.

```
startActivity(new Intent(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this, MainActivity.class));
```

MainAcivity class is,

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements FetchDataListener{
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        initView();   
    }

    private void initView() {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

        String url = "http://10.0.2.2/new/newA.php";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data) {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        setListAdapter(adapter);        
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg) {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if(dialog != null)  dialog.dismiss();
        // show failure message
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    }
}
```

So main activity class reference to the listview layout file. When debug the code above startactivity line is executed. But the problem is activity is not started. It means I can't show the listview

pls give answer to overcome this problem

Comment: Is `onCreate` called? Is `onFetchComplete` called?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer . because i didn't call mainactivity in my mainfist file
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your second activity added in `AndroidManifest.xml`?  Your manifest should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.package.name">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".AndroidPHPConnectionDemo"></activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
</manifest>
```

Just add an extra line under the `<application>` tag for your activity.